# slide com imagens miniaturas do banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

Estou desenvolvendo uma mini loja. Gostaria de ajuda para criar um slide pegando as imagens do banco de dados, de forma que elas fique formato de lista e quando clicar em qualquer uma delas, que a imagem selecionada apareça em outra div. E assim sucessivamente com as demais, transmitindo um efeito carousel. Se poderem mim ajudar fico grato.

Comment: Usuário novo? Leia a página [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como perguntar.